# How can i create a zip file of job's build folder in jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

So, I want to send the build artifactories to the jfrog artifactory. I want to create a zip file of the build folder which could be deployed later, it is in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/jobname/builds/123/*.

The problem is when in jenkins pipeline workspace which is /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jobname, it is capturing the raw file which is checked out from the git, not the compiled file from the build folder.

It seems I am not able to cd into build folder to make a zip file of the content. here is the content of the jenkin's pipeline

```
    stage("Zip Artifacts") {

      steps {
        sh ''' pwd '''
        sh ''' ls -la '''
        sh ''' cd $JENKINS_HOME/jobs/wip-job-backend/builds/${BUILD_NUMBER} '''
        sh ''' pwd '''
        sh ''' ls -la '''
        zip zipFile: "${jobname}/${BUILD_NUMBER}.zip", archive: false
        archiveArtifacts artifacts: "${jobname}/${BUILD_NUMBER}.zip", fingerprint: true
      }

    }
```

So, how can i create a zip file of the build folder which has all the compiled files that will be sent to artifactory. Currently the artifactory for the build number is showing this content which is not correct.

[artifactory image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbHpH.png)